# APC cache in Symfony2 for a multi language site

Tags: php, symfony, caching, apc

I'm looking for the solution for hours now, already looked in all the SO posts about that subject.

Here is my problem, I have a multi language website. I have 2 different types of routes, the french routes and the english ones.

The problem is that APC (in production env) considers that the two routes of a specific page are the same. So, for example, if I go to the french page after going to the english page, my variables are in english, so the translations too...

How can I fix it ?

Maybe there's a way to say to APC "those are two different pages"

Thanks

Comment: You are leaving us a little bit in the dark as to why would APC do such thing. What are you caching? What are your cache keys?

Comment: I'm caching all the website, I guess. I put `framework: validation: cache: apc`, `query_cache_driver:    apc` and `metadata_cache_driver: apc` in my config_prod.yml

Comment: Is the language part of the URL? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes it is. I store the url link with the LexikTranslationBundle. But I maybe find a solution, I use the detach function of the entity manager, and I can get my object with the new language. Didn't think about the Doctrine cache, but it seems to be that : `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->detach($myEntity);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that works for me. I thought it only was the APC cache of Symfony2, but it seems to be the Doctrine cache. So, I found the detach function of the entity manager. Doing it, I can get my entity with "refreshed" values, in the good language

```
<?php
    private function myController($myEntity) {
        $this->getDoctrine->getManager()->detach($myEntity);
        // getting my entity again with the repository
    }
```